# Name of a property that is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If I have a defined property or function on a class, I can get the name of it. e.g. I can get a class name with this...

```
console.log(`${this.constructor.name} is my name.);
```

or a function name with

```
fnA() {
  console.log(`There is a function called ${this.fnA.name});
}
```

---

But I want to know the name of a property/function that has not been declared i.e. the `typeof` is `undefined`. Which means `.name` fails.

**Is there a way to get the name in code of an `undefined` field?**

Or as [@skyboyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071697/skyboyer) [put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336257/name-of-field-that-is-undefined#comment81624281_47336257): *"(I'm) getting some function as a parameter and if it's undefined (I) would like to know what was original variable name"*

Something like this...

```
if (typeof this.missing == 'undefined') {
  console.log(`${getTheName(this.missing)} needs to be created.`);
}
```

Comment: @KenWhite Reading [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), it says "A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined." But the variable still exists in the code, and can be evaluated in some ways. So not everything about it is "undefined", that is just the primitive value it references.

Comment: do you mean you're getting some function as a parameter and if it's undefined you would like to know what was original variable name, don't you?

Comment: @skyboyer Yes, that is a much better way of phrasing it.

Comment: You cannot get the name of the variable a value was assigned to. It's simply not possible.

Comment: A property is not the same as a variable. If all you want to get is the property name, then you already know it since you are accessing the property. `if (typeof this.missing == 'undefined') { console.log("'missing' needs to be created.");
}`.

Comment: @FelixKing I understand - the terminology in JS is tripping me up all the time (coming from Java mostly). You are right, I meant a property or a function, and I have updated the question to reflect that. Apologies for the confusion; switching languages after so many years is fun/frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) handler trap:

```js
let ns = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, name) {
    if (name in target) {
      return target[name]
    }

    // handle missing values
    console.log(name)
  }
})

ns.contains = true

// does nothing
ns.contains

// logs 'missing'
ns.missing
```